# Random "InvalidOperationException" when changing date in CalendarView [UWP]

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, invalidoperationexception, calendarview

The code

```cs
private void DateChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var myDate = args.AddedDates.First();
    string parsedDate = myDate.ToString();
}
```

randomly causes this exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: You should check that args.AddedDates contains some elements before tying to get the first one and converting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to other answers, but `args` could also be null so I would use:

```
if (args?.AddedDates != null && args.AddedDates.Any())
{
    var myDate = args.AddedDates.First();
    string parsedDate = myDate.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:**

As has been pointed out, the above only works in C# 6.0 or higher. An alternative that will work in all versions is:

```
if (args != null && args.AddedDates != null && args.AddedDates.Any())
{
    var myDate = args.AddedDates.First();
    string parsedDate = myDate.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would add in a clause here to say that this (null conditions) will only work on c# 6+.

Comment: Fair point @Michael Coxon. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling `.First()` on something which doesn't contain anything/is empty. A better idea would be to call `FirstOrDefault()` which returns `null` instead of an exception if you call it on an empty collection.

```
var myDate = args.AddedDates.FirstOrDefault();
if(myDate != null)
    MyButton.Content = myDate.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that *args.AddedDates* is NULL or empty.
So to avoid this error, you'll need to check if it's not null or empty.

```
private void DateChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.AddedDates != null && args.AddedDates.Count > 0)
    {
        var myDate = args.AddedDates.First();
        string parsedDate = myDate.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple things you can do here...

First you can allow for an empty collection..

```
private void DateChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var myDate = args.AddedDates.FirstOrDefault();
    if (myDate != null)
    {
        string parsedDate = myDate.ToString();
    }
}
```

Secondly you could check the collection beforehand...

```
private void DateChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.AddedDates != null || args.AddedDates.Any())
    {
        var myDate = args.AddedDates.First();
        string parsedDate = myDate.ToString();
    }
}
```

Some simple debugging would have told you that the issue is probably in the `AddedDates` property.